# There is no such file or directory error in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, file, xamarin

Am trying to create a new text file in **Xamarin Android** and write some strings to that file but am getting an error that

> ENOENT(No such file or directory)

My code is explained below in detail

```
   //Create a new file where we will write some texts or strings called "SaveMe.txt"
 Java.IO.File root = new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments, "SaveMe.txt");
  //Check if file does not exist and create one 
   if(!root.Exists()){
        root.Mkdir();
    }
     //Define the content of the source file that we desire to access
       string content;
    //Read some texts from an asset file located in the Assets folder called "source.txt"
    try{
            AssetManager assets=this.Assets;
          //Define Steam reader that we will use to read the source file
       using (StreamReader streamReadr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("source.txt"))){
                    content = streamReadr.ReadLine();
            }
             //Define new File writer class that we will use to edit the target file with
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(root);
             //Add string from source file to target file
            writer.Append(content);
            writer.Flush();
            //Close file writer
            writer.Close();
       }catch(Java.IO.IOException m){
     //Capture the exception for debugging
       Toast.MakeText(this,m.Message,ToastLength.Long).Show(); 
       }
```

When I check in the Application's directories, I see Documents Directory but it's empty
Any suggestions that will succeed to create that text file and write to it will surely be appreciated

Comment: Please tell full path of your file. Using an Android 10 device?

Comment: `root.Mkdir();` Check the return value and handle accordingly.

Comment: why are you mixing Java.IO and System.IO?  What specific line causes the exception?

Comment: `When i check in the Application's directories` Please tell exactly what you do to check such.

Comment: @blackapps The source file called "source.txt" is in my project's Assets folder just like other child folders of the project like Resources

Comment: Then nothing of your code makes sense. If you first create a directory then it will not contain files. The directory you try to create has nothing to do with the assets directory in your project at design time. Further you did not tell the full path i asked for.

Comment: @blackapps, This path ```Android/Data/com.project/Files/Documents```I expect to see the file here

Comment: That is a relative path. Please tell full absolute path. Further a file in Assets will not be in Documents.

Comment: @Jason, They still can work together right?

Comment: @blackapps Okay let's start, there is a text file in Assets folder called ```source.txt```, it contains text, i want to read the first line and write that string to a new file called ```saveme.txt```

Comment: an Asset is not a file.  To access Assets use AssetManager - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows

Comment: Assets, like all items included in an app bundle/package, are read-only

Comment: @Jason, i have fonts in there and i accessed them the same way i accessed this text file and my intention is not to edit the text file in the assets folder, my intention is to read from it and transfer read content to another new text file if possible, thats why i specified ```Source file```(File we are reading from)``` and ```target file``` the file that is getting appended

Comment: @Jason, this is the line that is causing the exception ```FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(root);```

Comment: @Jason, i checked the microsoft documentation and am going to implement that assets manager logic into my code and be sure to come back with feedback

Comment: @Jason, I added the string to the toast message and its succedded to read from that txt file in the assets folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through my code and some posts on this forum, i discovered that you need to delimit the string file name with a back slash so that the compiler knows how to combine the directory and text file logic....

```
//Access the root directory of Android Os
 string abso = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
//Create New Folder in root called Tutorial
 Java.IO.File newfile = new Java.IO.File(file1, filename);
//Check if folder exists and create one if false
 if (!file1.Exists())
            {
                file1.Mkdir();
            }
//Read from the stream and assign value to string variable
   try
            {
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(assets.Open("source.txt"));
                
                    content = streamReader.ReadLine();
                      all = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                
            } catch (System.IO.IOException e)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, e.Message + " ", ToastLength.Long).Show();

            }
  //Define file name with folder delimiter character "/"
   string filename = "/target.txt";
   //Combine the dir and the file to create a java file
  Java.IO.File newfile = new Java.IO.File(file1, filename);
   //Check if file exists and create new one if false
     if (!newfile.Exists())
            {
                try
                {
                    newfile.CreateNewFile();
                }catch(Java.IO.IOException k)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, k.Message + " ", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
            }
   //Try to write to the file now  
            try
            {
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(newfile);
                fileWriter.Write(content);
                fileWriter.Append(all);
                fileWriter.Flush();
                fileWriter.Close();
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException j)
            {
                View view = this.FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.listener);
                Snackbar.Make(view, j.Message, Snackbar.LengthLong).Show();
            }
```

It worked and when i can succesfully find the text file in Storage

Comment: `/` is not an escape character. It is a folder delimiter.

Comment: @Cheesebaron,Yeah and it worked for me and am happy that my program can capture text from edit text and write string to some file in android os, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using `System.IO`? You will be able to write code that you can share between Android and iOS this way, and still write files, from shared code. The only part you would need to abstract away is to read the file from Android Assets.

Consider the following code:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;

var myDocuments = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

var myFile = Path.Combine(myDocuments, "myFiles", "SaveMe.txt");
var fileDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(myFile);
if (!Directory.Exists(fileDirectory))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(fileDirectory);

using var assetsStream = Assets.Open("source.txt");
using var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(myFile);
assetsStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
```

That is it! The `using` keyword makes sure things are flushed and disposed of.
You can also consider using `CopyToAsync` instead to not do blocking IO.

Some of these language features may require you to use `LangVersion` 7.3 or higher, you can add `<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>` to your csproj file in the first `<PropertyGroup>`

Note that some paths on Android, you will need to request permissions to write/read from that path. Make sure to read about requesting runtime permissions.

Comment: ,Am creating app for Android Platform currently

Comment: Hey got a link on a doc i could use to program the ime action key of soft input keyboard to make cursor in edit text break line?